# Robot framework version 4.1.3 -'BuiltIn.Set Variable' got unexpected named arguments(working fine for py2.7 and robot 3.1)

Tags: python, robotframework

> fetching json value from csv for each test_case_id  assigned to it at row level and while setting variable fetching json for one of the test caseid

```
   [Arguments]    ${test_case_id}
    &{config_jsons}    Read Test Data From CSV File    ConfigJsons.csv    cis
    &{json_config}    Set Variable    &{config_jsons}[${test_case_id}]
    log     &{json_config}
    [Return]    &{json_config}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `&` to specify a variable as an argument, robot will expand the variable to a set of key/value pairs. Instead, when referring to an individual value of a dictionary you need to use `$`

```
&{json_config}    Set Variable    ${config_jsons}[${test_case_id}]
#                                 ^
```

Comment: Yes I Used $ , its working for me